# Splitting up Copy/Paste without using Select

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an Excel macro in VBA. In a certain part of my code, I need to copy and paste one unmerged cell to a merged cell in a separate workbook. Part of this process is repetitive. The most efficient way for me to achieve this is to copy the cell and then `Call` a separate `Sub` with the location it will be pasted into. I have written a version using `Select` that works:

```
Sub Macro1()
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Copy
    Call Macro2

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

Workbooks("Protected_JD_Form.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("E46:G46").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

But I have been trying to move away from `Select` and this is the code I came up with:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
    Call Macro2

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

    Workbooks("Protected_JD_Form.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("E46:G46").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

This code gives me a 'PasteSpecial method of Range class failed' on the only line of Macro 2.

Is there a way to copy the contents of a cell and then `Call` a separate `Sub` with the destination and paste method, without using `Select`?

Edit: I understand that setting the values equal to each other is simpler than copy/paste. However, in this instance, that is not a possibility.

I also understand the pitfalls of merged cells. I get it. Seriously. But I don't have a choice as I am working with a customer's workbook, which can't be changed.

Edit #2: Following a comment from @ExcelHero, I rebooted my computer and ran the macro again. It worked. I have no idea what was going wrong. Regardless, credit to @ExcelHero for recognizing that my code was correct.

Comment: Why create a second macro just to paste? And why copy/paste in the first place? Just set the values of E46:G46 to A1.

Comment: dont merge cells. Use center across selection instead. Merged cells = xl nightmare

Comment: @ojf Believe me, I wouldn't if I had a choice. I do not, however. One of the workbooks I'm working with is Protected and also a template, I can't change the format of the cells.

Comment: @findwindow Part of the "repetitive process" I mentioned is that Macro2 is used multiple times. For instance, values are copied to a workbook using Macro2. The workbook is saved, closed, and another workbook is opened in it's place which also uses Macro2 to copy values.

Comment: This caught my attention because just reading through your code, it should not cause an error. So I tried it. I created two workbooks with [sheet1!e46:g46] merged in the second workbook. I tried your Macro1 and Macro2 (the versions without the selection) and they worked without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error resulted from the copy/pasting that I was doing while I was editing my code. Because the code I was copying was still on the clipboard, the macro tried to paste that into the cell, causing the error.

Lessons Learned:

- Limit use of the clipboard in VBA
- When copy/pasting in the coding window, double check to make sure that you are not affecting the existing code

Answer (score 0):

Why a second macro?

Anyways, if it's absolutely necessary, you're going to need to edit your second macros slightly.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim copyString As String


    copyString = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    Call Macro2(copyString)

End Sub
```

You'll notice that now `Macro2` is called with `copyString` after it.  This means, that you will run `Macro2`, and do something with whatever value is set to `copyString`.

```
Sub Macro2(text As String)

    'Workbooks("Protected_JD_Form.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("E46:G46").Value = text
    Workbooks("Protected_JD_Form.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("E46:G46").Value = text
End Sub
```

In this macro, you'll see I added `(text  as String)` to the macro name.  This will take some value (from `Macro1`, the value is the `copyString` variable), and then use it in the macro.  Does that make sense?

Again, I would only do this way if you absolutely need two macros for this copy/pasting.  If you can use just one macro, then these can be combined into a few simple lines:

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim copyString As String
copyString = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Workbooks("Protected_JD_Form.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("E46:G46").Value = copyString
End Sub
```

...or even further, cut out the `copyString` middleman (as @findwindow mentioned):

```
Sub macro4()
Workbooks("Protected_JD_Form.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("E46:G46").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but this defeats the purpose of having a second macro. The purpose of the second macro is to be a reusable way to paste whatever is copied in the first macro, which can change.

Comment: Will the second macro grow to be more robust?  If it's just going to stay the one line Paste, maybe consider just using that single line in your codes.  I don't know too much about VBA best practices, but I would think jumping from one macro to another, just to paste something, could cause headaches down the road, for debugging etc.  Maybe not though, just thinking aloud.

Answer (score 0):

This format worked for me - simply defining your copy range as a range and passing it to the first sub, and then iterating through the loop of declaring subsequent cells as the paste range, and passing that range on to the pasting sub:

```
Sub copy_paste()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Call copy_start(rng)

End Sub


Sub copy_start(ByVal copyRange As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    copyRange.copy

    For i = 1 To 5
        Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("B" & i)
        Call pasteover(rng)
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub pasteover(ByVal pasteRange As Range)

    pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```